# Prove that $16^x + 81^x + 625^x = 60^x + 90^x + 150^x$ has unique solution $x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> Determine the solutions of $16^x + 81^x + 625^x = 60^x + 90^x + 150^x$.

By graphing this with Desmos I know the only solution is $0$ and I was able to spot that myself. Where my hardship lies is with proving that there are no more solutions. I thought of a few things that might help but turned out ineffective: constructing a function from that equation and differentiating to its find critical points but that leads to an even harder equation; dividing the whole equation by a certain term (e.g. $625$ or $60$) such that on one side I'd have a strictly increasing function and on the other a strictly decreasing function, leading to at most a single solution, approach which doesn't work due to $625$, the biggest base, being put together with those two other small numbers; and finally I noticed $150^x=(60+90)^x$ but I suspect $150$ is nearly a random number in this problem (not that my observation helps in any way).

That being said, how would one prove that there is only the unique solution $x=0$ for that equation? Any help and hints are much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: define $a:=2^x,\,b:=3^x,\,c:=5^x$ so $a^4+b^4+c^4=abc(a+b+c)$. Now use the power means inequality plus AM-GM.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! From what you said, I got to $(\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3})^{\frac{1}{4}}=(abc\cdot \frac{a+b+c}{3})^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and from the AM-GM inequality it results eventually (after some calculations) that $\frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq (abc\cdot \frac{a+b+c}{3})^{\frac{1}{4}} \geq (abc)^{\frac{1}{3}} $ but I'm not sure how to use this further. I know that for the equality to hold $a=b=c$ but how would I prove from here that for my equation the equality is necessary?

Comment: J_n,  unless you include an @ sign with username , there is no guarantee of @J.G. being notified of your comment. You should get a notice flag of my comment as it follows your question post directly

Comment: @J__n Hint: Show that for $x > 0$, $c > b > a$?

Comment: @WillJagy I see, that's good to know. Thank you for pointing it out (and for tagging J.G. for me)!

Comment: @CalvinLin I think I got it! In the inequality from my comment above, I can replace the middle term using the equality from the same comment: $\frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq (\frac{a+b+c}{3})^{\frac{1}{4}}$. But, according to the power means, the inequality should be the reversed, so, by intersection, only the equality doesn't lead to a contradiction. Thus, $a = b = c$. Then with your hint, it is easy to prove that $c>b>a\ \forall x>0$ (nearly analogous for $x<0$ too), so that means $x=0$ is the unique solution. I'm 80% sure this is right, but if there are any comments to be made, please correct me!

Comment: Further hint: let $\mu,\,\sigma$ denote the AM and GM of $a,\,b,\,c$ so$$\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}\ge\mu^4\ge\mu\sigma^3.$$Now triple, and use the necessary condition to saturate the inequalities, $a=b=c$.

Comment: @J.G. now I got it. Thank you for walking me through this clever solution with hints, it is highly appreciated!